# What is the value of T when method parameter type is <? extends T> in Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I tried below code and little confused with generics. Can you please provide info on what is the value substituted for 'T' in the below method?

Code:

```
public class testT{

public static void main(String[] args){

List<Number> numbers1 = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers1.add(5.4);
        numbers1.add(2);
        numbers1.add(44444444l);
        getClass(numbers1);
}

static <T> void getClass(Collection<? extends T> collection) {
     for(T c : collection) {
       System.out.println(c.getClass().getName()); 
     }

}
```

Outputs:

```
java.lang.Double
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Long
```

Comment: `T` would be `Number`. Note that you don't actually need `T` at all for this code; `Collection<?>` and `Object` would work the same. Also, the `<? extends T>` isn't necessary, you could equivalently use `<T>`.

Comment: Its Number, as you bass a Collection of Numbers

Comment: @AndyTurner - Thanks. I also thought that <? extends T> is equivalent to <T> here. But having little difficulty in understanding how the compler derives T = Number here i.e. when an argument of Collection<Number> is passed to Collection<? extends T>, then i thought the case can be ambiguous to find the value of T.

Answer (score 0):

The `<T>` before your method return type indicates a generic method.

In turn, you can reference `T` in your method parameters, which you are doing: your only parameter is a `Collection` of types equals to `T` or extending it (the idiom `? extends T` defines the upper bound as `T` and uses a wildcard).

The collection you pass to your `getClass` method in your `main` method is a generic collection of `Number`s, in which you add a `Double`, an `Integer` and a `Long` (object wrappers of numerical primitives extend `Number`).

These types are inferred and boxed by the actual values you are passing through `add`.

Since the `getClass` method resolves at runtime, you are printing the specific types of your collection elements.

Comment: Thanks. but I'm trying to understand more on how the value T=Number is derived, when argument Collection<Number> is passed to Collection<? extends T>.

Comment: @AbhishekMJ your method will take any parametrized type for its given parameter. You happen to pass a `List<Number>`, hence `T` is a `Number`.